# Accessing JSON array data in VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have this json array and the data I need is in the array that starts data_id which I cannot extract. I am able to extract keys,value before the array but not in the array. I believe I need to request data in a specific way with a number in () after the fieldname nest but I cannot find a beginners explanation to see what number goes in the brackets and why you chose that number.

```
{"api":{"results":37,"data":[{"data_id":643951,"location_id":3005,"person":{"name":"Bob","country":"Turkey",
```

Any tips appreciated here is some code

```
'Print a few object variables before parse
         Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
    Set WrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("jsonoutput")
     
    WrkSht.Cells(1, 1).Value = xml_obj.responseText
   ' Displays data fine in one string as shown above

  
    'Parse the response
    Set jp = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xml_obj.responseText)
    
    For Each dict In jp
        Debug.Print dict
        If Not IsObject(jp(dict)) Then
            Debug.Print jp(dict)
        Else
            For Each subDict In jp(dict)
            Debug.Print subDict
            'Debug.Print jp(dict)(subDict)

            
            Next subDict
            
        End If
        
        Next dict
    

    ' I need to drill down into further levels but ?
```

End Sub

Comment: You'll get answers more quickly if you post your existing code...  Are you using a specific library to parse your JSON?  Always helps to provide that kind of detail.

Comment: Added some code hopefully that will help but it only gets me to the info above the array

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example

JSON used:

```json
{"api":{"results":37,
        "data":[{"data_id":643951,
             "location_id":3005,
                  "person":{"name":"Bob","country":"Turkey"}
                 } ]
}}
```

Code:

```vb
Sub Test36()

    Dim jso As Object, arr, data, obj

    'loading from a cell for testing...
    Set jso = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Sheet2.Range("A17").Value)
    
    'jso is a Dictionary
    Debug.Print jso("api")("results") '>> 37
    
    
    Set data = jso("api")("data")     'data is a Collection
    Debug.Print data.Count            ' >> 1
    
    For Each obj In data
        Debug.Print obj("data_id")           '>> 643951
        Debug.Print obj("person")("country") '>> Turkey
    Next obj
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would just share the code I ended up with. It can be improved on and some is over coded simply to make it easier to see where amendments can be made. Currently this will:

Access an API - just put as many header lines in as you need

Collect    the JSON data and flatten it to one level - this code will only work with Json where
blank values    are recorded as "null" rather than just "". You may
have to manually     correct the columns (or update the code) for
blank values

Ask you    which key you want to start with - it will
then mark that keys values    to start a new row each time it comes
across this

Make replacements    in the data to create delimiters
to mark which data is keys and which    is values

Pastes your keys
in row 1 that have values - dictionary       keys are ignored but
you can change that if needed

Remove all keys    from the string to
just leave values and paste those in the rows       below.

You need to have the RunScriptime XMl HTTP 6.0 and Object library ticked in Tools reference in VBA as well

```
Sub FlattenJsonGetDataFromKeysWithValues()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("yourworksheet").Range("a1:ZZ10000").ClearContents

Dim i As Long
'Declare variables
    Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    Dim base_url As String
        
    Dim Json1 As String, Json2, Json3, Json4, Json5, Json6, json7, Json8, Json9, Json10, Json11, Json12, Json13, Json14, Json15, Json16, Json17, Json18
    Dim Json0 As String
    Dim keys As String, keys2
    
'Create a new Request Object make sure in Tools-> reference the xml6.0, scripting runtime and object library are ticked
    
Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    'Define URL Components two headers are shown but you cana dd as many as required
    
    base_url = "https://yoururl.com"
    xml_obj.Open "GET", base_url
    xml_obj.SetRequestHeader "key", "55555"
    xml_obj.SetRequestHeader "host", "valuefor2ndheaderkeyifneeded"
    xml_obj.Send

   
    'Print the status code in case something went wrong

    MsgBox("The Request was " + CStr(xml_obj.Status))
    
    strJson0 = xml_obj.responseText
    
    MsgBox (Len(strJson0)) ' tells how long string is
    
    'Look for Json current delimiters and change all to a comma

    Json1 = strJson0
    Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?,:"
    Dim char As Variant
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
    Json1 = Replace(Json1, char, " ")
    Next
        


' Place @ before all field names, I have shown in this way so if needed you can vary to suit your needs

Json2 = Replace(Json1, "," & Chr(34), "@")                       ' Replaces ," - Chr(34) is a "
Json3 = Replace(Json2, ", " & Chr(34), "@")                      ' replaces , "
Json4 = Replace(Json3, Chr(34) & "   " & Chr(34), Chr(34) & "@") ' Replaces "   "
Json5 = Replace(Json4, Chr(34) & "  " & Chr(34), Chr(34) & "@")  ' Replaces "  "

'Place : after fieldname and before value

Json6 = Replace(Json5, Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34), ":")             'Replaces " "
json7 = Replace(Json6, Chr(34) & " ", ":")                       'Replaces "(blankspace)
Json8 = Replace(json7, Chr(34), ":")                             'Replaces "
Json9 = Replace(Json8, ":@", "@")                                'Replaces :@ with @
Json10 = Replace(Json9, "/", "")                                 'Removes /
Json11 = Replace(Json10, " ", "")                                'Removes blankspace
If Left(Json11, 1) = ":" Then Json11 = "@" & Right(Json11, (Len(Json11) - 1)) ' Replace : with @ if first character

' Now you just have field names (keys) marked by @ and values marked by :
' Find Field Names - which field should we start with? How many times is that key in the data


Dim firstkey As String
MsgBox (Json11) 'View this to see your key/header row options
firstkey = InputBox("Enter First Field/Key to locate") 'This will mark where all new rows start


keys = Json11
    
' Now take text between  @*@ as dictionary keys and ignore and text between   @*:  as headers for field names until repeat text is found in string by finding the firstkey you input above and putting a # marker in all heading that = firstkey

Dim openPos As Long
Dim closePos As Long

Dim k As Integer
Dim jsonFields As Collection
Set jsonFields = New Collection
Dim jsonValues As Collection
Set jsonValues = New Collection
   
' Find wanted starting key, skip over keys without value

k = 1
openPos = InStr(keys, firstkey)
closePos = InStr(openPos, keys, ":")
If InStr(1, Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos), "@") > 0 Then openPos = openPos + InStr(1, Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos), "@")
jsonFields.Add Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos)
keys = Replace(keys, firstkey & ":", ":#")
k = k + 1

' Find other keys with values, find dict keys

Do Until Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos) = ""
openPos = InStr(closePos, keys, "@") + 1
If k = 2 Then openPos = InStr(1, keys, "#")
closePos = InStr(openPos, keys, ":")
If InStr(1, Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos), "@") > 0 Then openPos = openPos + InStr(1, Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos), "@")
jsonFields.Add Mid(keys, openPos, closePos - openPos)
k = k + 1

Loop

    
' Find values and remove delimiters, keys and replace : in https values that are removed with other delimiters

y = 2 ' use to start populate rows
currentcolumn = 1
Dim r&
p = Split(keys, "@")
For r = 0 To UBound(p)
If InStr(1, p(r), ":") Then p(r) = Right(p(r), Len(p(r)) - InStr(1, p(r), ":") + 1) ' remove keys
If InStr(1, p(r), ":") = 0 Then p(r) = "" ' remove :
If InStr(1, p(r), ":") Then p(r) = Right(p(r), Len(p(r)) - InStr(1, p(r), ":")) ' set value  for collection to print later
If InStr(1, p(r), "https") Then p(r) = Replace(p(r), "https", "https:") ' fix https value by readding :
jsonValues.Add p(r) ' add to collection
Next r

' Print Values to worksheet

currentcolumn = 1
'Now Output your parsed key data, turn screen updating off  

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each Item In jsonFields

       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("yourworksheet").Cells(1, currentcolumn).Value = Item
       currentcolumn = currentcolumn + 1

Next Item

y = 2
currentcolumn = 1

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("yourworksheet")

For Each Item In jsonValues
       If Len(Item) > 0 Then

           If InStr(1, Item, "#") = 1 Then
               y = y + 1
               currentcolumn = 1
           End If
           ws.Cells(y, currentcolumn).Value = Item
           currentcolumn = currentcolumn + 1
       
       End If
     
Next Item

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```